# loop on array and get every 4 item of Li and add it to Ul list

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have this list of li with the class name list i need to loop on them and get every 4 list of them and append it to ul inside the div with class name first wrp i make the one with JavaScript and get 4 items but field to append it in ul because the is error called

"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

```js
var fristWrp = document.querySelector('.fristWrp');
  var list = document.querySelectorAll('.list');    
  var arrayList = Array.from(list);
    
    let iterations = Math.ceil(list.length / 4);
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        var chunk = arrayList.slice(i * 4, (i + 1) * 4);
        var createUl = document.createElement('ul');        
        fristWrp.appendChild(createUl);
        createUl.appendChild(chunk);                        
    }
```

```html
<div class="fristWrp">

</div>


<li class='list'>text 1</li>
<li class='list'>text 2</li>
<li class='list'>text 3</li>
<li class='list'>text 4</li>
<li class='list'>text 5</li>
<li class='list'>text 6</li>
<li class='list'>text 7</li>
<li class='list'>text 8</li>
<li class='list'>text 9</li>
<li class='list'>text 10</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chunk is an array. It should be

```
var fristWrp = document.querySelector('.fristWrp');
var list = document.querySelectorAll('.list');

var arrayList = Array.from(list);
let iterations = Math.ceil(list.length / 4);
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  var chunk = arrayList.slice(i * 4, (i + 1) * 4);
  var createUl = document.createElement('ul');
  fristWrp.appendChild(createUl);
  chunk.forEach(function(item) {
    createUl.appendChild(item);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could let the query selector do the hard work for you `:nth-child()`

```js
var fristWrp = document.querySelector('.fristWrp');
var list = document.querySelectorAll('.list:nth-child(4n+1)');    
Array.from(list).forEach((chunk) => {
  var createUl = document.createElement('ul');        
  fristWrp.appendChild(createUl);
  createUl.appendChild(chunk);                        
});
```

```html
<div class="fristWrp">

</div>


<li class='list'>text 1</li>
<li class='list'>text 2</li>
<li class='list'>text 3</li>
<li class='list'>text 4</li>
<li class='list'>text 5</li>
<li class='list'>text 6</li>
<li class='list'>text 7</li>
<li class='list'>text 8</li>
<li class='list'>text 9</li>
<li class='list'>text 10</li>
```